# Switch Mode Power Amplifiers

Tags: microwave

Suppose that in a switch mode power amplifier (class E or F) a 100% "non overlap" of current and voltage waveforms is achieved at the drain or collector.

How would there be any output power if there is no simultaneous voltage and current at any instant of time?

I know this sounds like a  very basic question but I couldn't find any answer to it in any text book or document on line

Comment: Because of energy storage components. I also note that you've asked 19 questions now and probably received some good answer so, for each of those questions that have good answer, select one answer and formally accept it. This is the payment for getting good advice.

Comment: Ali, isn't the idea is that the power is dissipated in the load - not in the power supply.

Comment: @Transistor Well, the power supply does consume current to charge its inductors and capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

> How would there be any output power if there is no simultaneous voltage and current at any instant of time?

The amplifier is ideally a switch. It switches from on-to-off and from off-to-on at those moments when voltage is zero and/or current is zero. Most of the cycle, significant current flows through the switch, or significant voltage appears across the switch, **but not voltage & current at the same time**.

- While the switch is **ON**, significant current flows through that switch, but very little voltage appears across its terminals.
- While the switch is **OFF**, significant voltage appears across it, but current flows elsewhere: current through the switch is near zero.

During the *very short time* spent switching, voltage across the switch is near zero. Or current through the switch is near zero, so very little power is dissipated while switching occurs.

Comment: The useful answer in my humble opinion is:

Comment: "Because of energy storage components"

Comment: @alikhalil why didn't you post that as an answer, then! Anyways, that answer is just a comically short contraction of what glen_geek wrote here, because the short half-sentence "because of energy storage components" doesn't answer your question at all. You can do a lot of things with energy storage components that will not lead to current flow and voltage being non-zero.

Comment: Simple: This is the answer I received from Andy aka. If you had taken the time to look at his answer you would have seen that this is not my answer but his. It does from my point of view answer the question. If you want please ask Andy aka

Comment: Of course Andy could have elaborated more in his answer but his very short answer gives a very useful hint. Is that clear to you now or not yet?

Comment: And by the way Mr. Marcus from what you wrote I do not believe you understand the issue so please next time when you make a comment on an issue you apparently do not understand, at least  don't come up with expressions  like "comically short contraction" Thank you! I am not going to waste my time more than that with you!

Comment: For once.... I'm not getting involved.

Comment: Well again you gave me the hint that made me see things clearly  as simple as that! Thank you